python3.9 how to find a compatible Spacy version
I need to re-deploy an existing very old python GCP Cloud Function that uses Spacy and other NLP stuff (that I am not familiar with) - to use a newer python runtime (3.9 or above) .
Sparing the details of an insane dependencies version conflicts chasing and adjustments  ... I came to the need to upgrade version of spacy from < 2.39 to > 3.0.x , and typer to > 1.4.0 ...
And the final issue I ran into doing this is:
The conflict is caused by:
The user requested typer==0.4.1
spacy 3.0.9 depends on typer<0.4.0 and >=0.3.0

which looks like I can't use a combination of spacy=3.0.9 and typer=0.4.1.
I cannot go below typer 0.4.1 (many rounds of version adjustments that were failing otherwise...)
Now I need to find a version of spacy that would work with typer=0.4.1 ....
I search and search - and can't find a way to figure out which versions of spacy woudl be compatible.... I tried to do a brute force guessing - trying all versions of spacy above 3.0.9 - and the first try of installing spacy>=4.0.0 caused this:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement spacy>=4.0.0 (from versions: 0.31, 0.32, 0.33, 0.40, 0.51, 0.52, 0.60, 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65, 0.67, 0.68, 0.70, 0.80, 0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 0.87, 0.88, 0.89, 0.90, 0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 0.100.0, 0.100.1, 0.100.2, 0.100.3, 0.100.4, 0.100.5, 0.100.6, 0.100.7, 0.101.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.5, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1.dev0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2.dev0, 2.0.2, 2.0.3.dev0, 2.0.3, 2.0.4.dev0, 2.0.4, 2.0.5.dev0, 2.0.5, 2.0.6.dev0, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.0.10.dev0, 2.0.10, 2.0.11.dev0, 2.0.11, 2.0.12.dev0, 2.0.12.dev1, 2.0.12, 2.0.13.dev0, 2.0.13.dev1, 2.0.13.dev2, 2.0.13.dev4, 2.0.13, 2.0.14.dev0, 2.0.14.dev1, 2.0.15, 2.0.16.dev0, 2.0.16, 2.0.17.dev0, 2.0.17.dev1, 2.0.17, 2.0.18.dev0, 2.0.18.dev1, 2.0.18, 2.1.0, 2.1.1.dev0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.1.7.dev0, 2.1.7, 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.2.0.dev10, 2.2.0.dev11, 2.2.0.dev13, 2.2.0.dev15, 2.2.0.dev17, 2.2.0.dev18, 2.2.0.dev19, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2.dev0, 2.2.2.dev4, 2.2.2, 2.2.3.dev0, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.3.0.dev1, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3.dev0, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, 3.0.0, 3.0.1.dev0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.0.6, 3.0.7, 3.0.8, 3.0.9, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.4, 3.1.5, 3.1.6, 3.1.7, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 3.2.4, 3.2.5, 3.2.6, 3.3.0.dev0, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 3.3.3, 3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3, 3.4.4, 3.5.0, 3.5.1, 3.5.2, 3.5.3, 3.5.4, 3.6.0.dev0, 3.6.0.dev1, 3.6.0, 3.6.1, 3.7.0.dev0, 3.7.0, 3.7.1, 3.7.2, 3.7.4, 3.7.5, 4.0.0.dev0, 4.0.0.dev1, 4.0.0.dev2, 4.0.0.dev3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for spacy>=4.0.0

This led me to think that I just do not understand how Spacy operates - it does not seem to be a "normal" Python library - that I could just specify a new version of in the requirements.txt ... Looks like a more involved installation process is needed, I suspect related to downloading some specific version of en_core_web_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz model (?) I see in this project  ...
So my question:
Could someone advise on which version of Spacy I shodul try that woudl be the closest to 3.0.9 - and what is the process of doing that?
Do I need to first get some new model archives?
Please excuse my ignorance of how Spacy+models work - I am not the original NLP developer who wrote all that cool stuff - I am just trying to fix a failed production cloud function until a real NLP developer could do a correct upgrade of the functionality ...
Longer explanation:
the last time this CF was deployed was in 2021 on python37 runtime. It stopped working now due to dependent microservice being moved to a different access point... In order to get this CF working again - I need to redeploy it with a new value for some env variable (use new service URL).
Sounds simple enough, but it is not! Because the CF cannot be deployed as is, using the original source code - due to changes in the current GCP python37 runtime libraries ...
Trying to deploy this CF "as is" - fails in GCP with:
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.functions.deploy) Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: found incompatible dependencies: "flask 2.2.5 has requirement click>=8.0, but you have click 7.1.2."

So, I am trying to make this project run on python39 runtime and upgrade the project dependencies - upgrade flask, then spacy, then typer, then hundred others :(-  and went through a multi-day hell of dependencies conflict resolutions - moving versions of different libs in the requirements.txt up and down, up and down, in circles....
If anyone has a suggestion for a less painful approach - please share!
Thank you!!!

Hi Marina, as I understand, you must use typer 0.4.1. But can you use any version between 3.0.9 and 4.0.0 of spacy?

yes, I think so. I was trying to jump to 4.x as I hoped that maybe in that version the issue with typer would be resolved  .....

I could install spacy 3.7.5 and typer 0.4.1 on python 3.9. I used conda to create a virtual environment and then: pip install spacy==3.7.5 typer==0.4.1. And they were successfully installed. Worth a try?

tried spacy==3.7.5 ERROR:  The conflict is caused by:
The user requested spacy==3.7.5
textacy 0.11.0 depends on spacy>=3.0.0
en-core-web-sm 3.0.0 depends on spacy<3.1.0 and >=3.0.0

looks like there indeed is some dependency between en-core-web-sm and spacy  versions... I just do not understand how they relate and how to check for compatible versions and fix them ...

based on your error, looks like you are asking for spacy>=4.0.0. Did you want spacy>=3.0.0?

no, the error says it is trying to use spacy 3.7.5 (which is what I specified in the requirements.txt): The conflict is caused by:
The user requested spacy==3.7.5
textacy 0.11.0 depends on spacy>=3.0.0
en-core-web-sm 3.0.0 depends on spacy<3.1.0 and >=3.0.0

I finally made this work. Here is everything I had to do:

manually installed spacy=3.7.5, which required:


upgrade thinc>=8.2.2


found a newer compatible version of the en-core-web-sm model, using this compatibility matrix - it was: en-core-web-sm 3.7.1   https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/blob/master/compatibility.json
downloaded pre-built wheel for this model: en_core_web_sm-3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl
added it to the CF data-input dir, and requirements.txt - replaced the old en_core_web_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz
added additional required dependency: functions-framework>3.0.0
finally was able to deployed to GCP !!

